# Solving $\log_x(a) = b $ and $\log_a(b) = x$ for $x$

Tags: logarithms

Solving for x:

$\log_a(x)=b \implies x=a^b$

$\log_x(a) = b \implies x = ?$

$\log_a(b) = x \implies x = ?$

Comment: the third one is so funny. if 2=x what is x?

Comment: Maybe funny for some, but for the third one answer like "x can be found as a solution of an equation $a^x=b$ gives more help :)

Comment: what are you trying to say? that is exactly the same as obviously the notion of logs has to be introduced before asking such questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second gives $$x=a^{\frac{1}{b}}$$ because there is the following property.
$$\log_{a^{\alpha}}b=\frac{1}{\alpha}\log_ab,$$ where $\alpha\neq0,$ $a>0$, $a\neq1$ and $b>0$.

Because  for $x=a^{\frac{1}{b}}$ we obtain:$$\log_xa=\log_{a^{\frac{1}{b}}}a=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{b}}\log_aa=b.$$

The third gives $$x=\log_ab$$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but how $log_x(a) = b$ is transformed using this identity: $\log_{a^{\alpha}}b=\frac{1}{\alpha}\log_ab$ ? Well, $log_x$ has nothing to do with $log_{x^{\alpha}}$, does it?

Comment: @user10777718 I added something. See now.